# Fragment listview with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a problem using AsyncTask to display a listview in my aplication, this is my code

`Public class Propiedades extends Fragment{`

```
//URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://10.72.13.88/TestCon/buscar.php";

    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_PROPIEDAD = "estado";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "idPropiedad";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "nombreReparto";
    private static final String TAG_DESC = "descripcionEspaniol";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";
    private static final String TAG_IMG = "imagen";
    AdaptadorProp adapter;

    private PropiedadList[] datos;
    private MiTareaAsincrona tarea1;
    private ListView lstListado;

    JSONArray user=null;
    JSONArray ruta=null;
    JSONObject c = null;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.propiedades, container, false);

         tarea1 = new MiTareaAsincrona();
         tarea1.execute();

         return rootView;       

    }   

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
        super.onActivityCreated(state);

        lstListado = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.LstListado);

        lstListado.setAdapter(new AdaptadorProp(this));

        /*lstListado.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int pos, long id) {
                if (listener!=null) {
                    listener.onCorreoSeleccionado(
                            (Correo)lstListado.getAdapter().getItem(pos));
                }
            }
        });*/
    }

    class AdaptadorProp extends ArrayAdapter<PropiedadList> {

        Activity context;

        AdaptadorProp(Fragment context) {
            super(context.getActivity(), R.layout.list_propiedad, datos);
            this.context = context.getActivity();
            System.out.println(datos);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_propiedad, null);

            TextView lblDe = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.title_propiedad);
            lblDe.setText(datos[position].getTitulo());

            TextView lblAsunto = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.detalle_propiedad);
            lblAsunto.setText(datos[position].getDetalle());

            return(item);
        }
    }               

    private class MiTareaAsincrona extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, PropiedadList[]> {

        @Override
        protected PropiedadList[] doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // Creating new JSON Parser
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json =new JSONObject();
            json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            //System.out.print(json);
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                //JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(TAG_USER);
                user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PROPIEDAD);
                ruta = json.getJSONArray(TAG_IMAGE);
                datos = new PropiedadList[user.length()];

                for(int i=0;i<=user.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(i);
                    datos[i] =  new PropiedadList(c.getString(TAG_NAME), c.getString(TAG_DESC), c.getString(TAG_ID));
                }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cargando!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cargando!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(PropiedadList[] result) {
            if(result!=null)
                System.out.println(datos);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tarea finalizada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText(Propiedades.this, 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tarea cancelada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }}`
```

the error log is this

```
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 13767
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767): java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Propiedades$AdaptadorProp.<init>(Propiedades.java:89)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Propiedades.onActivityCreated(Propiedades.java:71)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1708)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:908)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-30 10:22:40.754: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I´m trying to show the listview using my custom adapter AdaptadorProp before use AsyncTask the app works fine but now i have this problem, I´m new programing for android so i dont know what error i have

Comment: this code did not cause this stacktrace. (there is no new AdaptadorProp in onActivityCreated, apart from the commented one.) Put the AdaptadorProp creation in onPostExecute.